# remove the animation on a Button when click in a universal App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have defined this Style for my button in a universal App like this,I tried to remove the animation affected to the Button when I click on it

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BtnStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#1d84eb" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#1d84eb" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                      BorderBrush="Transparent"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                      Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I please remove the animation on the Button,when I click on it
thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

</VisualState>
```

Just delete everything in `<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">` state.

**EDIT**

Or delete whole `<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">`

Comment: thanks for your reply,but this will delete the color that I have affect to button when I press on it?is there please any way to delete animation and not changing the color when press?

Comment: To be absolutely clear: You have "PointerOver" blue-white animation - and its ok. So you want to change button colors just when pointer is over, but not when button is clicked? Just delete Pressed VisualState